# Should a function share two responsibilities or should we use a state checker function

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on a code which takes as input a list of resources, and attempts to lock each one of them. If anyone fails, it makes an effort to release locks on all the resources. This means either "ALL" resources have a lock Or none at all. I have two approaches, where I dont see any significant benefit over the other. What is the standard coding practice in such cases ? Is there  a name to any design pattern ?

```
OPTION 1:

// one function taking on 2 responsibilities. appears bad to have unlock code in locking function
public boolean getLock(List<Resource> resources) {
     for (Resource r : resources) {
          if (! Lock.getLock(r)) {
              releaseLocks(resources);   
              return false;
          }
     }
     return true;
}

OPTION 2:

    public boolean getLock(List<Resource> resources) {
         for (Resource r : resources) {
              if (! Lock.getLock(r)) { 
                  return false;
              }
         }
         return true;
    }

    public boolean stateChecker(List<Resource> resources) {
           if (!getLock(resouces)) {
               releaseLocks(resources);
               return false;
           } 
           return true;
    }
```

Comment: A lot will come down to context. Personally, I tried a use the second option mostly.  It might be required, based on the requirements (ie only one resource can hold a lock), that you may need the first, but you could also argue that you could also throw an exception if you try and get a new lock where a lock already exist

Comment: The main thing here is that all treads always attempt to lock resources **in the same order** to avoid deadlock or livelock.

Comment: Some thoughts.  Is the lock a property of the Resource - i.e. why is it not (boolean)r.lock(), (boolean)r.isLocked(), r.unlock()?  If it was they could be 'synchronized' (if needed - and if not, why are you locking them anyway?)  It looks like all these methods could be static (as currently given).  They should probably be final, anyway.  What stops something else (another threads, request, whatever) releasing an acquired lock when it shouldn't?  Is Resource an interface, or a concrete class?  Any of these may have bearing on how best to protected these resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function should always direct towards a single `responsibility`. Though the option 1 seems to be more elegant and also reducing the number lines of code, but towards maintainability standard view, it would be difficult for someone or you itself to construe the purpose of the function later when you re-visit.

**May be a weird example**, Just to state a real time example, we all play multiple roles in our life father, brother, husband etc etc. But we have separate `boxes` for each of these roles and their responsibility.

There is no `specific advantage`, but its always good to keep your function's responsibility as limited to the role defined.

Comment: I agree with the above comment... but not where it comes to resource management (locks, synchronization, etc).  It is a very common idiom to both query and lock resources in a single step.  In fact, in synchronized, multi-threaded code this is *essential* otherwise the resource may have become locked by the time you attempt to lock it (though it wasn't when you queried).  At that point you either have to check the locking worked (so you are querying again, in effect) or you have to be prepared for an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option *doesn't* unlock the (partially) acquired 'locks' even if it fails to get all of them.  (Or was getLocks() supposed to be private?)  How then will these resources get unlocked to free them up?  A method that either gets all the locks or guarantees no locks have been acquire sound much better.  (If not *guarantees* then how will these ever be freed up, BTW?)

If at all possible I would try to do something like this:

```
interface ResourceUpdater {
    public void useResources(List<Resource> rs);
}

public static boolean withResources(List<Resource> rs, ResourceUpdater updater) {
    // lock/unlock would ideally be private (or perhaps package private).
    // I'm also assuming the unlockAll() will be a no-op on the non-locked resources
    try {
        if(!lockAll(rs))
            return false;
        updater.useResources(rs);
        return true;
    }
    finally {
        unlockAll(rs);
    }
}
```

The point here is to make locking and unlocking a implementation detail of how you use the resources: client code that wants to use them does not need to be aware of the mechanism of the locking, as long as it always uses this means to update the resources.

Exactly where you put try...finally depends on the failure characteristics of your locking/unlocking and your operations.  (You might want to try to unlock each resource in a separate try...catch to make sure that at least an *attempt* is made to unlock each, for example.  Also, useResources() might want a return value, which is then returned from withResources().

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any advantage on the latter option, on the contrary. The name is "stateChecker", but it clearly does more than checks state, it tries to lock resources.

I would use option 1 and name the method `tryToLock(List<Resource> resources)` or similar.